# Ignore the '<' and '>' in the comand line in c

Tags: c, arrays

I made a program which takes numbers from the command line and adds them, the program is supposed to print an error if something else than a number is written, but when it reads > or < it creates text files with the results or rewrites on an already existing text file, if it doesn't exist it just stops without even running the code, is there a way to stop this from happening and read it just like another array?

Here is an example of the error

> $ ./a +24 < 5
>
> bash: 5: no such file or directory

Comment: Have you tried to escape it with \> or put it in quotes ">"?

Comment: you can use quotes for getting the input pure `./a "24 2 4"`

Comment: Textual information is preferred in textual shape inside the question, not as a link to a picture of text.

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures, and editors should not make the links into images (@chinmayan) when the picture is really just simple text.  If you're going to post a picture, don't post the whole screen; post just the text — and make sure it is big enough to be readable on a cell phone (hint: what is in this question is not big enough to be readable)!

Answer (score 4):

That's not your program - that's the shell file I/O redirection. If you want your program to see the `<` or `>`, escape them appropriately:

```
./a +24 \<5
```

Answer (score 1):

As ths others have said, it is not your program acting up, but the command line shell uses < and > as input/output redirection operators. You could escape them with backslashes.

But rather than forcing the users to escape each < and > (and possibly some other special characters like $ and the parentheses), you can quote the whole command line:

```
./a '1 < 24'
```

The whole command now is in `argv[1]`. You still have to parse it. As a bonus, there is no need to insert annoying spaces between the tokens anymore:

```
./a '1<24'
```